# ERROR: IndexError :: list index out of range aws deployment error

Tags: amazon-web-services

ERROR: IndexError :: list index out of range aws deployment error

When I am trying to deploy in aws I got this problem.
Previously it was working fine.I did not made any changes in elastickbeanstalk config.Please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same problem while using `'eb deploy'` command. Try to debug it with `'eb deploy --verbose --debug'`.

In my case there was a problem with command line input, as stated in debug output:

```
\ebcli\operations\commonops.py", line 709, in create_app_version
    description = source_control.get_message()
\ebcli\objects\sourcecontrol.py", line 186, in get_message
    return stdout.split(' ', 1)[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This code tries to get your commit message and if you don't use one it throws IndexError. The solution is to commit again with message different than empty string.